# Forms authentication & subdomain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, authentication, subdomain

I'm trying to use forms authentication that will work for both my top level domain & sub domains.

for example, if I log in with this domain: *mydomain.com* and afterwards going to *www.mydomain.com* i want to have the ability to identify the user who logged on to *mydomain.com* (it's the same application).

i'm using the following in my **web.config** file:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" domain="mydomain.com" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

This is an **mvc** project, and i'm getting the user id with the following **API**:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

The creation of form authentication cookie is done by the following api after performing openid logon to the user:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, createPersistentCookie);
```

I can see that the authentication cookie is being sent to both domain but only the domain that the authentication was made against recognizes the user.

Am i doing something wrong?

Thanks,
Lior

Comment: possible duplicate of [Forms Authentication across Sub-Domains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/608120/forms-authentication-across-sub-domains)

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have the same [machine keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx) setup for those two applications. If the authentication token is encrypted with the machine key of application 1 and application 2 has different key it won't be able to decrypt it.

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608120/forms-authentication-across-sub-domains) isn't exactly the same as yours, but it looks like it's the solution your looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You need to issue your ticket in the toplevel domain, in order to be recognized by subdomains. This is because of how cookies work:

If you set the cookie in domain.com it will be visible on sub.domain.com
However if you set it on sub.domain.com, it will not be visible on domain.com

This is a security issue because of cookies and you'll have to consider it, beyond the settings of the `<form>` element which have to do with validating/rejecting a authentication cookie, where you will need to have `domain='domain.com'`, which you already do.

In addition to all this, if on the subdomain you have a different application, you will need to explicitly define the machine key to be the same. You can generate your self some keys here: http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey