# How to login sense/net from another asp.net website?

Tags: asp.net, sensenet

I have a website build by asp.net, and want to embed sensenet web app into my website(maybe using iframe?), how can I handle the authentication for sensenet? Or are there any other ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options to achieve this, it mostly depends on your application structure, and what parts of Sense/Net do you want to use.
I recommend to give a try to [Sense/Net ECM 7.0](https://github.com/SenseNet/sensenet#GettingStarted). It's in Beta stage at the moment, but you can already use the core functionality (e.g. the Content Repository, OData API, WebDav, etc...) and it's very easy to install from NuGet to an existing Asp.NET MVC project.

There is no GUI layer included at the moment, but you can use Sense/NET directly from your Asp.Net application.
If you want to use the Sense/Net WebPages Gui, there will be a package also available soon from NuGet.

If you want to keep your website separated, you can authenticate with [Basic Auth](http://wiki.sensenet.com/How_to_authenticate_from_custom_tools), but with the next update, SN7 will support JWT authentication

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm trying to integrate sensenet 6.5, my website and sensenet website are separate website, I just want to use sensenet's content repository function and the document list UI in my web site(use iframe).  I can get response from [Basic Auth](http://wiki.sensenet.com/How_to_authenticate_from_custom_tools), but don't know how to pass the authentication to the sensenet in iframe. Could you please give me some suggestion? Sorry, I'm new for sensenet.

Comment: I think you can try to redirect requests from a specific route from your web site to the SenseNet site, you can check this answer as an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6375201/7418775