# Cross-subdomain MVC4 .NET membership with jquery.load

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-membership

I have this website on myWebsite.com (MVC4).

Then I have this other website on en.myWebsite.com.

The MVC4 website has a fairly typical .NET membership, and in there I have this /Header/Index/ controller / action that generate the header, in different ways if the user is logged on. This works.

Both websites have `<httpCookies domain=".myWebsite.com"></httpCookies>` in their web.configs.

From my subdomain, I jquery.load the "myWebsite.com/Header/" into a div in my page.

My problem is that when I check "User.Identity.IsAuthenticated", I get false even though I should be authentified.

What should I do to get this to work properly? Thanks!

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/608120/forms-authentication-across-sub-domains

Comment: If I run locally with debug, I can see that the cookies are not sent. Even though they should. I have the domain set in my web.config and the cross domain headers. "<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />"