# Migrating aspx to mvc issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, form-authentication

I have migrated from aspx page mvc to mvc razor.

I am using form authentication which is authenticated from the parent domain.
[Forms Authentication across Sub-Domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608120/forms-authentication-across-sub-domains)

```
<forms name=".auth" 
             loginUrl="http://external.com/Login/Login_form.aspx" 
             defaultUrl="~/Home/Index"
             domain="external.com" protection="All" timeout="30" path="/" 
             requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" cookieless="externalProfile"/>
```

After authenticated the user, I am redirecting the user.
I have cached the application error and checked, the redirection doesnot work.

It always redirecting to the **default.aspx** which is not there in my project and **"The file '/Views/Shared/Site.Master' does not exist."**

Comment: I think your provided info still incomplete. Can you show ASPX page markup & other supporting configurations? Try arranging `RazorViewEngine` before `WebFormViewEngine` in `ViewEngines.Engines`.

Comment: ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
            ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());
I have added this to clear the webformviewengine. but still no luck